# functions called in_app.js won't always load at some point next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I want to add a user behavior tracking in my next.js application. I am using Next 10.2.3. In the _app.js I have a function that will call the tracking to start once the page is loaded. I have the impression that every time the page is loaded the function in _app.js will load(reload) as well but unfortunately at some point it does not. Let me know if these are correct or I miss understood some part. This app is hosted in vercel. how the code looks like below.

```
import App from "next/app";
import Head from "next/head";
import * as tool from "../lib/tools";

const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {

tool.callUserBehavior(); //i want to call this function everytime the page is rendered/loaded

  return (
        <>
    
      <Head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href={getStrapiMedia(global.favicon.url)} />
      </Head>
      
      {/* Display the content */}

      <Layout global={global}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
       </>
  );
};

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  // Calls page's `getInitialProps` and fills `appProps.pageProps`
  const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(ctx);
  // Fetch global site settings from Strapi
  const global = await getGlobalData();
  // Pass the data to our page via props
  return { ...appProps, pageProps: { global, path: ctx.pathname } };
};

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: Have you tried moving your function call to a [`useEffect` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) callback? For instance, `useEffect(() => { tool.callUserBehavior(); });`.

Comment: actually even a plain console.log in the useeffect hasnt been call every time i refresh the page! not sure what is the problem

Comment: I would follow the Google Analytics example: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-google-analytics

Comment: yep i follow that too.. but still it did not work